# How to disable Alt+F4 in a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to disable Alt+F4 in a WinForms app. Where do I need to add the code?

```
namespace FileName
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Form.FormClosing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing) -- Read what's in the the Remarks section.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this if you want to prevent all user close operations (click on form close X in the corner for example as well as AltF4)

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the `FormClosing` event:
This does not affect you using other methods to close the window.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: `F4` is not a Modifier Key.

Comment: Hi Jiale. Could you respond to @Jimi's remark please?

Comment: where did ModiferKeys come from?

Comment: `ModifierKeys` can determine if Alt is pressed. I did read jimi's comment. F4 is not a Modifier Key. Currently I haven't found a good direct replacement. You can simply judge the status of alt and close alt+F4. If you use `if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) e.Cancel = true;` , the user will not be able to close the program manually, I want to avoid this operation as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

combine both of them

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```